# Which protocol (FTP or HTTP) is better for download/upload small or large files?

Tags: http, upload, ftp, download, protocols

I was looking at different websites where download options are available, and always find different way to download same file. Over FTP or HTTP. I was wondering which one is better and should preferred over the other one? And why?

Comment: just choose the faster web server, :)

Comment: But my question is, technically which one is better? I mean is there any pros or one over the other?

Comment: Then I think FTP as it called File Transfer Protocol

Answer (score 3):

The question should not be a server question, but rather a client question.  Are the clients to be web browsers?  If so, HTTP.  If they're advanced &| you want to have a system-user-based control over several files, then FTP.  FTP has some side benefits, but only if your user/consumer/client can take advantage.

Comment: so assuming we have advanced client, what benefit does client have with FTP over HTTP?

Comment: Generally FTP clients can resume file transfer if aborted, additionally FTP can be used to facilitate transfers between 2nd- and 3rd-parties.  FTP (generally) maintains object ownership of authenticated clients and generally will not overflow HTTP size mandates on upload.